# Is an elliptic curve geometrically connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

According to Katz & Mazur's book "Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves", an elliptic curve $E$ over an arbitrary scheme $S$ is a proper smooth curve over $S$ with geometrically connected fibers all of genus $1$ and given with a section $"0"$. Note that "smooth curve" is defined as a smooth morphism $E\rightarrow S$ of relative dimension $1$ which is separated and of finite presentation.

In Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" however, an elliptic curve is a pair $(E,O)$ where $E$ is a smooth curve of genus $1$ and $O\in E$. By "curve", it is meant a projective variety of dimension $1$.

It seems to me that both definition differ concerning the hypothesis of being geometrically connected. I know that an elliptic curve over a field (eg. $\mathbb{R}$) may not be connected, but what about an algebraically closed field? Using Silverman's definition, is it true that an elliptic curve may not be geometrically connected?

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: As I understand it, elliptic curves over $\Bbb R$ are geometrically connected; essentially this means that after base extension to the algebraic closure, the scheme obtained is connected as a scheme.

Comment: Well, this is indeed straightforward given Katz & Mazur's definition for instance, but how can one show it using Silverman's one? Why would a regular Weierstraß equation over an algebraically closed field produce a connected scheme? I can't manage to show this actually (and couldn't find data about it on the internet).

Comment: A Weierstrass equation defines an irreducible nonsingular curve in $P^2$ with exactly one generic point...

Comment: Oh, right, just as simple as that.. Thank you very much, sometimes I just spectacularly miss the point!

Comment: A note: an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{R}$ may have two connected components in the analytic topology, but it is certainly always connected in the Zariski topology.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @BrandonCarter :)

Comment: A connected group scheme is always geometrically connected (so this applies also to abelian varieties). More concretely, you should be able to show that a smooth curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is (geometrically) connected.